# how to display/hide block on homepage depending the value in user profile field?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I'm currently displaying a block on my D7 site' homepage.

Now I've a requirement to display that block only if the logged in user has a specific value in their profile.

I know it can be done using php evaluation by navigating to the bottom of the block and then click (Pages > Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE ) but have no experience in writing php scripts.

```
global $user;

If($user->your_profile_field_value == 'requiredvalue') 
{ 
// display the block 
// display the block only on 'homepage' } 
Else { // don't display the block }
```

I'm new to php can someone please help me fill in the blanks in above code snippet.

thanks

Comment: Writting code is a good choice. Though views (https://www.drupal.org/project/views) could provide an alternative if you need, considering a contextual filter + relationship with user profile fields in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PHP visibility settings to display the block if user has requiredvalue. Once you've created the block that you want to display (or not display) add the following code to the "Page specific visibility settings" in the block configuration menu:

```
 <?php 
    global $user;

    If($user->your_profile_field_value == 'requiredvalue' && drupal_is_front_page()) {
    return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;

    ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. How do I then only display this block only on home/front page as once I select the visibility option I'm no longer able to list my pages by selecting option 'Only the listed pages' in block settings

Comment: try passing && drupal_is_front_page() check if you can achieve

Comment: To make block visible on front page add following snippet to blocks 'Page specific visibility settings' and make sure using as PHP

<?php
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    return TRUE;
  }
?>
or to hide it the reverse

<?php
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    return FALSE;
  }
?>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Mahesh v but no luck so far. I'm thinking if it is because the user field I'm tying to access is a custom field. please look at my code below<?php 
    global $user;

    If($user->field_current_employer == 'TWSXV' && drupal_is_front_page()) {
    return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;

    ?>

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom module and implement this code

```
 /**Implementation of hook_preprocess_HOOK().  */

 function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables)
 {   
  global $user;
  if($user->your_profile_field_value == 'requiredvalue')  
  {
     if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
         return TRUE;
        // for front page only condition  
     }
    // your code
  }
 }
```

you can also add this in your current enable theme by just replace

`mymodule` to your `themename`

Comment: "have no experience in writing php scripts." There's no way he'll get from here to what he needs.